# WinSCP fails to run as a WebJob on Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, winscp, azure-appservice, winscp-net

I've developed a **.Net console application** to run as a **webjob under Azure App Service**.

This console app is using WinSCP to transfer files from App Service Filesystem to an on-prem FTP Server.

- The connectivity between App Service & the on-perm FTP server is Okay.
- Most of the time the job succeeds ,the files are synced, and log files written as well.
- Sometimes, the job fails, no files synced, and no Log is NOT being written as well.
- The Exception that is being fired intermittently on ALL of our Azure environments (Dev, Test, Prod):

> WinSCP process terminated with exit code -1073741819 (C0000005). There was no output. Response log file D:\local\Temp\wscp550C.03E988EE.tmp was not created. This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself.

Any Clues ?

**My code snippet ..**

```
///Session Options
            var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = host,
                UserName = userName,
                Password = password,
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = sshHostKeyFingerprint
            };
///Opening Session & Sync Files
                using (var session = new Session())
                {
                    var timestmp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") + ".txt";
                    session.SessionLogPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionLogPath"] + timestmp;
                    session.XmlLogPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlLogPath"] + timestmp;
                    session.XmlLogPreserve = true;
                    session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);
                    var syncResult = session.SynchronizeDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Remote, localFolder, remoteFolder, false,false);
                    syncResult.Check();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

*C0000005* means *"(memory) access violation"*. That probably indicates that WinSCP has crashed. It might mean a bug in WinSCP. Make sure you have the latest version. Otherwise, you better report this on [WinSCP support forum](https://winscp.net/forum/), as software bugs do not really belong to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> WinSCP process terminated with exit code -1073741819 (C0000005). There was no output. Response log file D:\local\Temp\wscp550C.03E988EE.tmp was not created. This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself.

The error messages shows that you don’t give an write permission on production. Please give all `write` permission in **Production Environment**.

WinSCP could not create/write to log file that it uses to report back to the  [.NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) . Make sure your process has **write permissions** to the temporary folder. Alternatively, you can ***use*** (undocumented) ***property*** `Session.XmlLogPath` to change the log file location.

Refer [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_library_timeout_waiting_to_respond)

Comment: Doesn't C0000005 mean *"(memory) access violation"* rather than file system permissions issue?

Comment: The exceptions happens intermittently, i.e., most of the time the job is completed successfully and sometimes it gives that exception.

Comment: Regarding the "write" permission, I think I can not do this in App Service, since the webjob contents are being copied to run under a temp directory which I can't administrate. The only valid solution I can see, is to control the output path of such temp logs "...\wscp0DE0.0234E2B0.tmp"

Comment: Ad "The exceptions happens intermittently" – That's quite important piece of information,  and you never mentioned that in your question.

Comment: I've configured Session.XmlLogPath to a different directory and still have the issue

Comment: The temporary log file file location requires the write permission. Can you give a try